# Color input text to red except inputs inside "skip" class

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to color only input of type text with the exception of inputs of type text inside class called `skip`.

```html
<label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>
<div class="skip">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
</div>

<input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, using the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```css
*:not(.skip) > input[type="text"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>
  <div class="skip">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
</body>
```

You could also do something like this:

```css
input[type="text"]{
  color:red;
}
.skip input[type="text"]{
  color:unset;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>
  <div class="skip">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe :

```css
input[type="text"]{
    background: red;
}

.skip input[type="text"]{
    background: white;
}
```

```html
 <label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>
 <div class ="skip">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
 </div>

 <input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

Or

```css
*:not(.skip)>input[type="text"]{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
 <label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>
 <div class ="skip">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
 </div>

 <input type="text" id="name1" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input:not() pseudo-class and apply to everything but the skip class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend an easy solution of setting the color of your input text to red. Then also setting the input text of the skip class to your default color (like black). Like this:

```
input[type=text] {
    color: red;
}

.skip input[type=text] {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you need something like this:

```
body > input[type="text"] {
  background-color : #d1d1d1; 
}
```

You pick input of type text that is child of body.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use classes to label each class. So in the input you want to be red, just make its class `make-red`:

```css
.make-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

<input class="make-red" type="text" id="name1" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

If you want *everything* except the one input to be red, just give it a "no-red" class and give the following

```
* {
    color: red;
}
.no-red {
    color: black;
}
```